# Node.JS HTTPS client requests doesn't validate the server certificate against it's given ca certificate

Tags: node.js, https, client, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create a client in NodeJs that will validate the server certificate it connects to.
I haven't found examples/documentation on the subject, and the example at
https://github.com/vanjakom/JavaScriptPlayground/blob/master/client_server_ssl_nodejs/client.js
doesn't fail the server, although the server certificate doesn't comply with the ca.crt used by the client.

can anyone suggest a way to verify the server certificate by the client?

slightly modified code from the site origin:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    path: '/test',
    method: 'GET',
    //key: fs.readFileSync("keys/userB.key"),
    //cert: fs.readFileSync("certs/userB.crt"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("ca.crt")

    ,rejectUnauthorized:true,
    requestCert:true,
    agent:false
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.log(""+d);
    });
});

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Does the single ca file represent the whole certificate verification chain? You can pass an array to the ca parameter.

Comment: yes the single CA was enough, but thanks for the reminder